# looping infinitely when using sqlcmd inside a while-loop body

Tags: bash, ksh, sqlcmd

I have a bash script which uses `sqlcmd` for fetching data from database in a **while-loop** body:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
echo -e "1\n2" > tmpfile
echo "---------------content from the tmp file--------------"
cat tmpfile
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
  echo "${line}"
  echo "   ------------sqlcmd operation start------------"
  sqlcmd -Q "set nocount on;select 'dummy'"  
  echo -e "   ------------sqlcmd operation done------------\n\n"
done < tmpfile
echo "-----------------------script done---------------------"
```

It is expected to interate based on the line of content in the file.txt, that is twice in this cases, but acutally it will interate the first line infinitely:
[image: output is infinite]

I got the anwser about how to resolve the infinite loop from here [loop variables stuck as constant when using sqlcmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107257/loop-variables-stuck-as-constant-when-using-sqlcmd)

and here [Unexpected behavior of file descriptor and/or I/O streams after running sqlcmd with -i option (read sql from file) in ksh creates infinite loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311251/unexpected-behavior-of-file-descriptor-and-or-i-o-streams-after-running-sqlcmd-w).

Simply put, it can be resolved if we redirect the input stream, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
echo -e "1\n2" > tmpfile
echo "---------------content from the tmp file--------------"
cat tmpfile
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
  echo "${line}"
  echo "   ------------sqlcmd operation start------------"
  sqlcmd -Q "set nocount on;select 'dummy'" < /dev/null  
  echo -e "   ------------sqlcmd operation done------------\n\n"
done < tmpfile
echo "-----------------------script done---------------------"
```

[image: output is expected]

Below script which is just replace `sqlcmd` with other command, e.g. `date` then it is normal. I think it can prove this issue is relative to `sqlcmd`:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
echo -e "1\n2" > tmpfile
echo "---------------content from the tmp file--------------"
cat tmpfile
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
  echo "${line}"
  echo "   ------------sqlcmd operation start------------"
  #sqlcmd -Q "set nocount on;select 'dummy'"
  date
  echo -e "   ------------sqlcmd operation done------------\n\n"
done < tmpfile
echo "-----------------------script done---------------------"
```

[image: no sqlcmd then output is normal]

More interesting, if the content of the file is less than 4 charaters(including invisible char), it woudn't cause infinite iteration:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
#less than 4 char -- normal
echo -ne "123" > tmpfile
echo "---------------content from the tmp file--------------"
cat tmpfile
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
  echo "${line}"
  echo "   ------------sqlcmd operation start------------"
  sqlcmd -Q "set nocount on;select 'dummy'"
  #date
  echo -e "   ------------sqlcmd operation done------------\n\n"
done < tmpfile
echo "-----------------------script done---------------------"
```

[image: normal when less than 4 chars]

Infinite when there is more than 3 charaters:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
#more than 3 chars -- infinite
echo -ne "1234" > tmpfile
echo "---------------content from the tmp file--------------"
cat tmpfile
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
  echo "${line}"
  echo "   ------------sqlcmd operation start------------"
  sqlcmd -Q "set nocount on;select 'dummy'"
  #date
  echo -e "   ------------sqlcmd operation done------------\n\n"
done < tmpfile
echo "-----------------------script done---------------------"
```

[image: more than 3 charaters then infinite]

All in all, I'm curious how `sqlcmd` leads to the infinite looping.
I can understand that the `sqlcmd` inherits the input stream from the outsiede `while loop`, and as it inhereists the input stream, if it slurps the conent then it should lead to less iteration for the outside `while loop`, but how it is possible cause looping infinitely?

Comment: `read` sets `$line` to the first line of `file.txt` and `sqlcmd` probably slurps all remaining lines during the first iteration of your `while` loop. As you added `|| [[ -n $line ]]` after your `read` command, and as this always evaluates as true, your loop never exits. Remove `|| [[ -n $line ]]`.

Comment: Thank you, Renaud Pacalet. Actually it still continuely loop even we remove `|| [[ -n $line ]]`

Comment: I do not see how this is possible. Please edit your question and show the exact code your are now running, the exact content of `file.txt` and the exact output you see.

Comment: @Raindy if you can truly reproduce this problem without `|| [[ -n $line ]]` then remove that from the code in your question as it's by far the most likely cause of your issue. Similarly if you can have `< /dev/null` after the sql command and still have a problem then show that in your example.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you replace `sqlcmd...` with some other command, e.g. `date`? You don't show how `file.txt` is being populated - could some other process be writing to it while this one is sleeping?

Comment: @EdMorton No, if there is no sqlcmd invoked inside the `while loop`, it wouldn't loop infinitely.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Raindy, why did you tag "ksh"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is that `sqlcmd` uses [lseek](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) to set the file offset for its standard input back to the start of the file.  Certainly, doing that would cause the infinite loop problem.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code uses `perl` to reproduce the problem:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    perl -e 'seek(STDIN, 0, 0)'
done <"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
```

Running a file containing this code with Bash generates output

```
#! /bin/bash -p
#! /bin/bash -p
#! /bin/bash -p
...
```

until it is interrupted.

One way to verify this theory would be to run the shell program with [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (`strace -f -o strace.out SHELLPROG`).  I expect the output to include something like this for the `sqlcmd` process:

```
... lseek(0, 0, SEEK_SET)           = 0
```

Comment: Amazing!!!
I believe that is the root cause.  I do find the `lseek` command from the debug trace:


`lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)`

Comment: I asked ChatGPT before if it is possible to reset the input stream in bash shell.
He told me it is imposible. stupid AI, LOL

Comment: @Raindy it's a perl command that's resetting the input stream, not [directly] a bash shell. Try asking ChatGPT if it is possible to reset the input stream using a Unix command as that's a different question. The consistent problem I see with ChatGPT is that it answers the question that was asked :-). We had one on SE a couple of weeks back where someone asked ChatGPT how to do X, it generated some code to mostly do X, and then the OP asked on SE how to fix/enhance it. Turned out the OP didnt need any of that code, they just had to quote their variables - ChatGPT didn't know that but people did

Comment: I'd be surprised if ChatGPT could generate decent-quality shell code.  Almost all shell code on the internet is bad.  Most of it is atrocious.  There is almost nowhere for ChatGPT to get consistently good shell code.